# cypher merge executed results java

Tags: java, merge, cypher

I have two queries:

I run this query in one method

```
String query = "MATCH (g:Grid {name:'"+gridLocation+"'})<-[r:WILL_GO]-(t:Taxi)"
                    + "WHERE r.reachedTime <= '"+userPickUp+"' RETURN t.name AS Taxi";

Result taxiWillGo = graphDb.execute(query);
```

And in another method

```
String query2 = "MATCH p=((g:Grid {name:'"+gridLocation+"'})-[r:TO*1..2]-(g2:Grid)), (g2)-[r2:LOCATION]-(t:Taxi) "
                    + "WITH  t, p, REDUCE(totalTime = 0, x IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) | totalTime + x.time) AS totalTime "
                    + "WHERE totalTime <= 6 RETURN t.name as Taxi LIMIT 3";

Result taxiNeighbor = graphDb.execute(query2);
```

Both queries return the same element (a taxi), is it possible to merge both executed Results into a single one so at the end i have one "table" displaying all results.

```
WILL_GO Taxis: 
 +----------+
| Taxi     |
+----------+
| "taxi 4" |
+----------+
NEIGHBOR Taxis:
 +----------+
| Taxi     |
+----------+
| "taxi 2" |
| "taxi 1" |
| "taxi 4" |
+----------+

e.g Merged Table WILL GO and NEIGHBOR
     +----------+
    | Taxi     |
    +----------+
    | "taxi 2" |
    | "taxi 1" |
    | "taxi 4" |
    +----------+
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `UNION` Cypher clause to combine the results of two queries: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-union.html

```
MATCH ...
RETURN t

UNION

MATCH ...
RETURN t
```